# How to disable creation of spaces on macbook?

Tags: macbook-pro, mojave, spaces

How to disable creation of desktop workspaces on macbook?

Somehow they get created when I don't need them. [OS: Mojave]

Comment: You mean ‘real’ Spaces or Fullscreen Spaces?

Comment: @Tetsujin i don't know what is the difference. i am referring to windows that are shown on top when we click mission control. (`F3` button)

basically sometimes i can't see all the windows on the same screen. have to swipe on touchpad to see another window.

Comment: Fullscreen apps each generate their own temporary un-numbered Space. There’s no ’fix’ for this other than not using Fullscreen. Without further information there’s little else anyone can say.

Comment: Jeez he clearly meant "real spaces". You jumped to a conclusion that was unfounded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there’s no window on a space, do the three finger swipe up gesture or F3 and you can hover on the top left corner of the thumbnail and a cross appears. Just delete the space.

If there is some window on some space, you can drag it and bring to the other space to make the previous one empty. In the same mission control state, hold the window in one space and drag it to destination thumbnail.

If it is made by a full screen app, as Tetsujin says, it cannot be deleted and when app returns to its original space, the other one is automatically deleted.

Answer (score 2):

The following sets the delay for creating a new space to 6000 seconds, i.e. 100 minutes. So if you drag a window to the edge of the screen, it won't create a new window unless you hold it there for 100 minutes.

```
defaults write com.apple.dock workspaces-edge-delay -float 6000
```